# How to get a button to fill the full width of the footer in Mobile View?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a button that's found in the right rail column on my test page (in desktop view) to take up the entire footer of the page in mobile view.

This is the css and js code that I am using:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        #register_text_container {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
        }
}

$(function() { //doc ready
    if (!($.browser == "msie" && $.browser.version < 7)) {
        var target = "#register_text_container", top = $(target).offset().top - parseFloat($(target).css("margin-top").replace(/auto/, 0));
        $(window).scroll(function(event) {
            if (top <= $(this).scrollTop()) {
                $(target).addClass("fixed");
            } else {
                $(target).removeClass("fixed");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The js code is not mine, it is one I found searching stackoverflow and its been working great, I just can't seem to figure out how to get it fill the page. I have tried using `width: 100%` but that didn't work.

The container that I'm calling in my CSS code is one I do not have direct access to, its built into the CMS and pops up as a button.

when I inspect the Register button to look at the html code to see what I should be calling in my css document this is what I found:

```
    <div class="entry-page-button-container" id="register_link_container">
    <div class="manageable-content" data-container="edit_register_text_container">
   <a class="entry-text-link secondary-step step-button"   id="register_text_container" href="">Register</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried it on each class and id and so far still unable to get the register button to take up the full width of the page.

Appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!

[Test Page](http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR?fr_id=21959&pg=entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `width: 250px !important` on this link `.entry-text-link secondary-step step-button`
Change it to `width:100%;` (and remove the `!important`, it is not needed ).

Then add `left:0;` and `right:0;` in this `fixed` element `.entry-page-button-container`

And it should works properly.

Comment: This would also work, but maybe remove the !Important :-). If anything is trying to add small adjustments to the button for visual effects, it'll overwrite it

Comment: Of course, it needs to be removed :) It is not needed in any case.

Comment: Just making sure ;-D We've all had the 'why isn't it working' moment when CSS is being overwritten by a team mates CSS

Comment: Yes, but I think using `!important` is not a good way to adopt, it's better to play more efficiently with selectors. :)

Comment: I know it's not good practice, and I shouldn't technically use it (my fellow devs hate it :), however, it is helpful for those quick fixes.

Comment: agh ive been editing this colleagues css for a week now and I've still got places that are conflicting lol, thank you or pointing that out. This fixes it!

Comment: You're welcome ! I think it's not a good practice because it will overides all other selector even if they have a higher specificity. You can use it sometimes to overide some javascript inline style but when you are dealing with CSS, I prefer to think about selectors I use and understand why it don't works before using `!important` :)

Comment: ohhh i see, okay good to know because this CSS document has `!imporant` all over the place lol I'll keep an eye out for that when making adjustments

Answer (score 1):

just set the width of the button element to 100%. This will make it take up the full width of the button's parent container.

Set it using the style attribute like so:

```
<div>
<button style="width: 100%">Press this full width button!</button>
</div>
```

this will make the button go to the full width of the parent div element

Comment: unfortunately, the HTML document where that element sits I do not have access to. Is there a way to do it through css?

Comment: Sure, just do a reference in CSS using either the .class identifier or the #id identifier. Then give it the 100% width attribute as before.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `width : 250px !important` on `<a>` element and add this on fixed element.

```
width: 100%;
left: 0;
bottom: -10px;
```